# Are warforged PCs affected by Mirror of Life Trapping and other spells/abilities that don't affect constructs?

Tags: dnd-5e, warforged

Are warforged PCs affected by Mirror of Life Trapping and other spells/abilities that don't affect constructs?

I have seen in similar questions that, by intent, they can be healed by *cure wounds* and the like, as they can be affected by any spell/ability that targets constructs *or* living creatures.

My question is more on the negative side of things. If they are subject to a save that a construct automatically succeeds, do they still roll?

Comment: Are you talking about the warforged in the *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron*, specifically the version from [this UA](https://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/723UA_EberronRaces7232018.pdf)? (It may change when the WGtE is finalized.) Note that a previous version appeared in an [outdated UA from 2015](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/UA_Eberron_v1.pdf).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Yes, they are affected

Warforged are just like humans when it comes to how they are affected by spells.: From the ["Living Steel and Stone"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/warforged#LivingSteelandStone) section of the Warforged race's description (WGtE, p. 67; my emphasis):

> While they’re formed from stone and steel, **warforged are living humanoids**. Resting, healing magic, and the Medicine skill all provide the same benefits to warforged that they do to other humanoids.

### Previous editions

But that is the 5th edition description. In 3rd and 4th edition, they were considered "Living Constructs" which meant they were considered both as constructs and as living beings.

Comment: In previous editions there were also unaffected by healing and required construct specific healing.  There was also a lot more construct specific magic in general.